Understanding row item size in CSS flexbox
I'm learning CSS flexbox. I have created the mockup shown below. The green box is a flexbox item in a flexbox row layout. I have troubles understanding why that green box does not fill the space all the way to the right of the browser window.
Mockup layout
Why is that? I am looking for an explanation not an easy fix (I've tried to find the answer on mdn web docs. I'm sure it's out there somewhere, but I couldn't find it.)
Here is a runnable snippet:


.page {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.flex-row {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-wrap {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.align-items-center {
  align-items: center;
}

.m-10 {
  margin: 10px;
}

.h-40 {
  height: 40px;
}

.h-100 {
  height: 100px;
}

.w-100 {
  width: 100px;
}

.w-200 {
  width: 200px;
}

.w-800 {
  width: 800px;
}

.bg-lightblue {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.bg-aqua {
  background-color: aqua;
}

.bg-lightgreen {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.bg-crimson {
  background-color: crimson;
}

.bg-lightgray {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.bg-darkgray {
  background-color: darkgrey;
}
<body>
  <div class="">
    <div class="navbar-top h-40 bg-lightgray">Navbar top</div>
    <div class="page flex-row bg-darkgray">
      <!-- first element in row-->
      <div class="navbar-left w-200 bg-aqua">Navbar left</div>
      <!--second elemen in row (much longer than first)-->
      <div class="content w-800">
        <div class=" flex-col align-items-center bg-lightgreen">
          <div class="box bg-lightgray w-100 h-100 m-10">A</div>
          <div class="box bg-lightgray w-100 h-100 m-10">B</div>
          <div class="box bg-lightgray w-100 h-100 m-10">A</div>
          <div class="box bg-lightgray w-100 h-100 m-10">B</div>
          <div class="box bg-lightgray w-100 h-100 m-10">A</div>
          <div class="box bg-lightgray w-100 h-100 m-10">B</div>
          <div class="box bg-lightgray w-100 h-100 m-10">A</div>
          <div class="box bg-lightgray w-100 h-100 m-10">B</div>
          <div class="box bg-lightgray w-100 h-100 m-10">A</div>
          <div class="box bg-lightgray w-100 h-100 m-10">B</div>
          <div class="box bg-lightgray w-100 h-100 m-10">A</div>
          <div class="box bg-lightgray w-100 h-100 m-10">B</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer h-40 bg-crimson">footer</div>
  </div>
</body>




Please include your code as a runnable snippet. External links are frowned upon when a Stack Snippet will just do fine as it forces people trying to help to leave the site. Also you seem to be using some kind of frontend framework like Bootstrap. Please add the appropriate tags.

@connexo on it ...

There is no "page" element for this css page {   min-height: 100vh; }

The answer from @MarkSchultheiss is correct - your code is functioning exactly as written. It's rendering at a width of 800px because you told it to - if you change that to 100% it will take up 100% of the available space

@MarkSchultheiss It is in the fourth row from the top 

No it is NOT page { for an element <page> is NOT the same as .page { for a class class="page  Details matter.

@MarkSchultheiss Would have been easier to write that a point symbol is missing. I'm just a beginner, but thanks anyway.

You said is is 800px so it is 800 PX not the width of the view
.w-800 {
  width: 800px;
}


So true! Shouldn't post questions when I get too tired. Follow up question though. When I remove the w-800, the green box shrinks to the size of the elements in side. Why is that? I would have expected the element to grow all the way to the right.

That is another question but you would need to clarify " grow all the way to the right" in that might mean "take all the space to the right" OR take "all the parent space" - which would move the light gray to the right also; or something else.

Seems to be easier to go looking on MDN myself, but thanks anyway.
